# Struct field with reserved name golang

Tags: struct, go, reserved-words

Hi Im doing an API client and I want to use a struct to pull out the json, the problem is that one of the json fields should be named type, as far as I know it is a reserved keyword, how can I create a struct with a "type" field in it?

Example:

What I want to do:

```
type Card struct {
  cardId  string
  name    string
  cardSet string
  type    string
}
```

Comment: Read the [package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) (preferably before asking questions). It'll tell you two important things, a) you need to export your fields and b) you can use a struct tag to rename the fields to/from JSON.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That won't work because you're not exporting the field names. To use different field names in the JSON output, you can use struct tags. For example, to name the fields CardID, Name, CardSet, and Type in the JSON output, you can define your struct like this:

```
type Card struct {
    CardID  string `json:"cardId"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    CardSet string `json:"cardSet"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
}
```

The `json:"<name>"` tags specify the field names to use in the JSON output.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use json annotations on your model. Also, the fields have to be exported (upper case) or the unmarshaller won't be able to make use of them.

```
type Card struct {
  CardId  string `json:"cardId"`
  Name    string `json:"name"`
  CardSet string `json:"cardSet"`
  TheType    string  `json:"type"`
}
```